# Using naive bayes to predict new values

Tags: r, naivebayes

I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
weather <- c("good", "good", "good", "bad", "bad", "good")
temp <- c("high", "low", "low", "high", "low", "low")
golf <- c("yes", "no", "yes", "no", "yes" , "no")
df <- data.frame(weather, temp, golf)
```

What I would like to do now is using the naive bayes method to get probability of this new dataset

```
df_new <- data.frame(weather = "good", temp = "low")
```

Therefore I try

```
library(e1071)
model <- naiveBayes(golf ~.,data=df)
predict(model, df_new)
```

But this gives me:

```
NO
```

Any idea how i can turn this into a probability?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

probabilities are returned if you use `type = "raw"`

```
predict(model, df_new, type = "raw")
no yes
[1,] 0.5 0.5

predict(model, df_new, type = "class")
[1] no
Levels: no yes
```